# Sending and receiving messages via AX.25 and GNURADIO

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have two USRP B200 connected to two Raspberry Pi's that I want to communicate via AX.25. Here are the flowgraphs:

TX:
[image]

RX:
[image]

They work well and are able to communicate. However, if I change the samp_rate to 200k on both the TX and RX, the RX is not able to receive the messages sent. However, if I use Direwolf with RTL-SDR, I am able to receive the messages sent at 200k. Can anybody help me how to receive the data sent at 200k?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is really an outdated version of GNU Radio. [gr-ax25](https://github.com/dl1ksv/gr-ax25) is ported to GNU Radio 3.9 and 3.8; please use a modern GNU Radio (3.8 or 3.9), that solves a lot of problems you'd otherwise run into later on.

Also, as UHD will print to the console, 150 kS/s is lower than any sampling rate than any USRP actually supports, and hence is substituted for a different one – which works, because both ends of the communication do the same!

It's still not "proper". You need use a higher rate (recommendation: 1 MS/s) and use a resampler to go down to the very low AX.25 rates; the "rational resampler" block will do that!

Then, you misconfigured both your NBFM TX and RX – your quadrature rate is *not* the 48 kHz you configured, but your actual sampling rate / 4.

Of course, as long as both ends of the communication are "wrong in the same way", they have a chance of working together. But any actually correct receiver implementation won't be able to make out what you meant to send.

I'd recommend you look into the apps/ subofolder of dl1ksv's gr-ax25. That contains a properly set up APRS transceiver, for a sampling rate of 192 kS/s; I'd recommend you replace the fcdproplus blocks with your UHD USRP source/sink blocks and use a rational resampler, so that at the USRP Source you decimate by 16, and on the USRP Sink you interpolate by 16. Your sampling rate for both Sink and Source would then be 192000*16.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and comments. I tried to follow your suggestion and install gr-ax25 on GNU Radio 3.8. However, I am having a hard time installing it as there were errors during the install. Is there any chance that you can help me or point me in the proper direction on how to install this properly?